# How to mock local RestTemplate in Spring boot to solve connection refused?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

Here is my code.What I want to do is to test three kinds of exceptions.But I don't know how to mock local variable restTemplate.

my code:

```
private void setJobInstanceInfo(JobInstance jobInstance, String uri, String group, String jobName) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> type = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        };
        try {
            String resultStr = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
            HashMap<String, Object> resultMap = JsonUtil.toEntity(resultStr, type);
            setJobInstanceIdAndUri(jobInstance, resultMap);
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            LOGGER.error("spark session {} has overdue, set state as unknown!\n {}", jobInstance.getSessionId(), e.getMessage());
            setJobInstanceUnknownStatus(jobInstance);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("jobInstance jsonStr convert to map failed. {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Livy status is illegal. {}", group, jobName, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

When call `restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class)`,it always throws exception as below:

`"I/O error on GET request for url: Connection refused: connect".`

I know it's url problem.That's what I want to mock and return anything I expect.
So,can you give methods to test this three kinds of exception of RestClientException and  IOException and IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: Any reason not making rest template a class variable and instantiating it once in constructor or even injecting it as a dependency?

Answer (score 1):

At first do not instantiate the RestTemplate in your methods! Let Spring create it for you, e.g. add this to a spring configuration

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

Then you can start writing a rest client test like described here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-rest-client

Comment: Thanks  for your answer.But we already instantiate the RestTemplate in my methods and there are many similar places.So do you have any other ways ?

Comment: If you really need one rest template per method and want to mock it, then another option is to give it as parameter from outside to the method, which in turn needs to have this rest template located somewhere configurable, thus letting you to mock it.